# res is not defined in ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Objective: I need to display different templates based on route. In my case it's /edit /new, and I need a condition to display tabs or something else.

In my `router.get('/edit' cb)` I tested this: `res.url.includes('new')` which returned true. I went inside my header.ejs and ran a condition:

```
<% if(res.url.includes('new')) { %>
  <h1>Something else</h1>
<% } else { %>
  <h1>This</h1>
<% } %>
```

However, it's telling me that *res is not defined*. My question is this: whats the best way to do this? My first instinct is to just create another header file but that's going to duplicate a lot of code but I may be over optimizing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to do `res.render('template.ejs', { res: res });`

check if u forgot to pass the `{ res: res }`